# Return Multiple Result Sets from MYSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How do you return multiple result sets from a MYSQL Stored Procedure?

This is my test stored proc:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`hlamAdmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM hlam.member;

   SELECT * 
   FROM hlam.security;

END
```

Now when I call this:

```
Call test()
```

I only receive one resultset. How do I receive both? I am used to MSSQL I apologize if this is an easy question.

Comment: Never say apology when you asking a question. We all here for learning.

Comment: Are you want result sets in jdbc(java) or within mysql only, i have solution for java where you can get both result sets

Answer (score 1):

You could try to either JOIN them (Linking them together) or use UNION (Combine two selects in one);

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
select a.col1, b.col1
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

```
select name as col1, surname as col2 from table1
union
select location as col1, desc as col2 from table2;
```

John

Answer (score 0):

Using HeidiSQL (free MySQL client), I get both resultsets, but on two different tabs.