# Do not operate a stored procedure at php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

In our application when multiple stored procedure In a piece of code php Just call first stored procedure Acts and the rest did not return any results

Comment: I appreciate English might not be your first language, but could try explaining a few different ways? It's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: If you're trying to get multiple result sets from a single query, I'm not sure it's supported by the php mysql client. This might be a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375361/return-multiple-result-sets-from-mysql-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), you can fetch multiple result sets using [nextRowset](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php)